# QByteArray to Double in Qt C++ 5.8.0

Tags: c++, qt, qtserialport

I have a serial comport data read write program. Data is being read from the comport 4 (Eg: 1022), but when I'm trying to do a mathematical calculation of the data 1022/2 then its give me output as `0.5  5.0  51.00  511.0` means its not taking the whole 1022 as a single number for the mathematical calculation. Its take 1 first then divide 1/2=0.5 then once 0 digit receive it take as 10/2=5 and so on. But I want 1022 as a single digit number like (eg: 1022/2=511)

I have tried to convert the QByteArray into Double for the calculation.

[image: output]

```
     void MainWindow::readData()
 {
     QByteArray data = serial->readAll();
     bool ok;
     QByteArray cata= QByteArray::number(data.toDouble(&ok)/2);

    console->putData(cata);
 }
```

Comment: A typical debuging technique in Qt is to use `qdebug()`; use it to see if you have read the data correctly. It'd be nice if you can use `bytesAvailable()` to see if there's any data available before processing.

Comment: @rakib_ thank for you response, i already check with qdebug() it receiving the same data vertically. I want the data to convert into double and the do some mathematical calculation with the received that .. that it. thank you ..

Comment: In serial communication a number is a bunch of serialized data. Is not possibile send 1022 number as is. It will be spit in code for "1" code for "0" and so on. What you must to do is know how may byte compose your number, group it and then convert raw data to your effective number.

Comment: You can also send your double as a string, send it, receive the string (there are so many examples you can find about it) and then use a QVariant to make it back as a double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here an example of a **TCP client/server** in Qt. the server sends 1022.72, and the client receives it and shows the result value divided by 2. (run the server then the client:

**Server Code:**

test.pro:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2017-06-26T12:49:54
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = test
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QHostAddress>
#include <QAbstractSocket>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    _server(this)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    _server.listen(QHostAddress::Any, 4242);
    connect(&_server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(onNewConnection()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;

}

void MainWindow::onNewConnection()
{
   QTcpSocket *clientSocket = _server.nextPendingConnection();
   connect(clientSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onReadyRead()));
   connect(clientSocket, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)), this, SLOT(onSocketStateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)));

    _sockets.push_back(clientSocket);
    for (QTcpSocket* socket : _sockets) {
        double data = 1022.72;
//        socket->write(QByteArray::fromStdString(clientSocket->peerAddress().toString().toStdString() + " connected to server !\n"));
        socket->write(QByteArray::fromStdString(QVariant(data).toString().toStdString()));
    }
}

void MainWindow::onSocketStateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState socketState)
{
    if (socketState == QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState)
    {
        QTcpSocket* sender = static_cast<QTcpSocket*>(QObject::sender());
        _sockets.removeOne(sender);
    }
}

void MainWindow::onReadyRead()
{
    QTcpSocket* sender = static_cast<QTcpSocket*>(QObject::sender());
    QByteArray datas = sender->readAll();
    for (QTcpSocket* socket : _sockets) {
        if (socket != sender)
            socket->write(QByteArray::fromStdString(sender->peerAddress().toString().toStdString() + ": " + datas.toStdString()));
    }
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void onNewConnection();
    void onSocketStateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState socketState);
    void onReadyRead();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QTcpServer  _server;
    QList<QTcpSocket*>  _sockets;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.ui: (empty)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
    <item>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>400</width>
     <height>25</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**Client code:**

test2.pro:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2017-06-26T14:34:11
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = test2
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QHostAddress>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    _socket(this)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    _socket.connectToHost(QHostAddress("127.0.0.1"), 4242);
    connect(&_socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onReadyRead()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::onReadyRead()
{
    QByteArray datas = _socket.readAll();

    qDebug() << QVariant(datas).toDouble() / 2;

    ui->label->setText(QVariant(QVariant(datas).toDouble() / 2).toString());

    _socket.write(QByteArray("ok !\n"));
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTcpSocket>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void onReadyRead();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QTcpSocket  _socket;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.ui: (result written here and also with qDebug)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
    <item>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>400</width>
     <height>25</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: @Elia how can I do that exactly I dont know how to do it. could you please tell me?